# Dont run a cron php task until last one has finished

Tags: php, linux, bash, concurrency, cron

I have a `php-cli` script that is run by `cron` every `5 minutes`. Because this interval is short, `multiple processes` are run at the same time. That's not what I want, since this script has to write inside a text file a numeric `id` that is incremented each time. It happens that `writers` are writing at the same time on this text file, and the value written is incorrect.

I have tried to use php's `flock` function to block writing in the file, when another process is writing on it but it doesnt work.

```php
$fw = fopen($path, 'r+');
if (flock($fw, LOCK_EX)) {
    ftruncate($fw, 0);
    fwrite($fw, $latestid);
    fflush($fw);
    flock($fw, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($fw);
```

So I suppose that the solution to this is create a `bash` script that verifies if there is an instance of this `php script` that is running, if so it should wait until it finished. But I dont know how to do it, any ideas?

Comment: The script is running for more than 5 minutes?

Comment: Just to be clear, the other process is also using flock, correct?

Comment: @etherous, yes it's the same `php script` that is run by all processes.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, yes because there are insertions on a `mysql` database that can sometimes make the script run for more that 5 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I'm using with a `bash script` is this:

```bsh
exec 9>/path/to/lock/file
if ! flock -n 9  ; then
    echo "another instance is running";
    exit 1
fi
# this now runs under the lock until 9 is closed (it will be closed automatically when the script ends)
```

A file descriptor `9>` is created in `/var/lock/file`, and `flock` will exit a new process that's trying to run, unless there is no other instance of the script that is running.

[How can I ensure that only one instance of a script is running at a time (mutual exclusion)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)

Comment: Very interesting, had now idea about creating "file descriptors" using exec. http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/30/23-File-descriptors/

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand how incrementing a counter every 5 minutes will result in multiple processes trying to write the counter file at the same time, but...

A much simpler approach is to use a simple locking mechanism similar to the below:

```
<?php

$lock_filename = 'nobodyshouldincrementthecounterwhenthisfileishere';

if(file_exists($lock_filename)) {
  return;
}

touch($lock_filename);

// your stuff...

unlink($lock_filename);
```

This as a simple approach will not deal with a situation when the script breaks before it could remove the lock file, in which case it would never run again until it is removed.

More sophisticated approaches are also possible as you suggest, e.g. fork the job in its own process, write the PID into a file, then before running the job it could be checked whether that PID is still running.

Comment: Incrementing isnt an issue when there is only one process that is incrementing it at same time. But as I say there are other operations in this script that make it run for more that 5 minutes (crawling & insertion).

Comment: Well, in that case, if you don't want any of those processes to skip an increment, the ideal way is instead of simply `return` when lock file exists, keep it in a loop which `sleep`s for a second or so then rechecks lock file.

Comment: I wont sleep the process since it'll run 5 minutes later, I think I'll use a bash lock using `flock` [mutual exclusion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/045)

Comment: The solution, that uses a file as a flag or indicator to prevent start of the next session of the same program, is not robust, because if the locking file will onetime not be deleted (assume, that something goes wrong), then this solution will be not able to recover such temporary damage autonomically.

To get such solution robust you need to add active monitoring of age of the lock file. If its age will exceed a reasonable threshold, then the active monitoring must delete this lock file.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent start of a next session of any program until the previous session still running, such as next cron job, I recommend to use either built into your program or external check of running  process of this program.  Just execute before starting of your program

```
 ps -ef|grep <process_name>|grep -v grep|wc -l
```

and check, if its result will be 0. Only in this case your program could be started. 
I suppose, that you must guarantee an absence of 3rd party process having similar name. (For this purpose give your program a longer and unique name). And a name of your program must not contain pattern "grep".

This work good in combination with normal regular starting of your program, that is configured in a cron table, by cron daemon.
For the case if your check is written as an external script, an entry in the crontab might look like

```
 <time_specification>  <your_starter_script>  <your_program> ...
```

2 important remarks: Exit code of your_starter_script must be 0 in case of not starting of your program and it would be better to completely prohibit writing to stdout or stderr by this script.

Such starter is very short and a simple programming exercise. Therefore I don't feel a need to provide its complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cron` to run your script every 5 minutes, how about using `at` to schedule your script to run again, 5 minutes after it finishes.  Near the end of your script, you can use shell_exec() to run an `at` command to schedule your script to run again in 5 minutes, like so:

```
at now + 5 minutes /path/to/script
```

Comment: Such solution using "at" is not robust. If onetime anything goes wrong, e.g. process has been killed or temporary issue with UNIX Linux scheduling mechanism (overloading), then the chain of "reincarnations" will be broken, so that you need to organize a "babysitter" i.e. more than simple monitoring, that watches the chain and restarts it if it was broken.

Comment: that's not very efficient, it's cron's task to schedule processes (you dont have to reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 0):

Or, perhaps even simpler than my previous answer (using `at` to schedule the script to run again in 5 minutes) is make your script a daemon, by using a non-terminating loop, like so:

```
while(1) {
  // whatever your script does here....
  sleep(300) //wait 5 minutes
}
```

Then, you can do away with scheduling by way of `cron` or `at` altogether.  Just simply run your script in the background from the command line, like so:

```
/path/to/your/script &
```

Or, add `/path/to/your/script` in /etc/rc.local to make your script start automatically when the machine boots.